# Keyboard is not detected

Tags: keyboard

Am having a P4 system of 1.4Ghz speed. The problem is that my PS2 keyboard is not detected in this system. When I reboots the system the keyboard lights will blink but later it is not working on this system. I had checked this keayboard in my friends system and its working finely. So what might be the problem???

Comment: Check your bios settings. Some have an option for usb/ps2 keyboard.

Comment: Even for entering into bios also i have to use keyboard. Where here is the main problem is of keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Try another known-to-be-working ps/2 keyboard with the system.

If that doesn't work, then try a known-to-be-working USB keyboard with the system.

Answer (score -1):

With Windows 10 I have a usb mouse plugged into usb port and a ps2 keyboard plugged into a ps2 port. The keyboard stopped working after I temporarily used a usb keyboard. I was cleaning the keys on the other. 
I have a solution:  With both plugged in, go to settings/devices. Click on usb-ps/2 Optical Mouse.
Yes, I know it's mouse and not keyboard. Before you remove device on the mouse (Yes that's what you must do), know that you'll lose mouse control. Backing out will be a chore. Just use the power button and power down or pull the plug, unless you want to tab your way to a power down. I'm not sure how. When you power back up, everything should work. I have win 10 upgrade to this date Jan. 12, 2018.